# How to pass a PHP variable to an AngularJS config

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Let's say I have a HTML file that has AngularJS loaded in with 'ngRoute'.

Then I'm initialize the app by making an `index.php` file (I'm not displaying the basic HTML tags + angular JS includes here):

```
<?php $path = 'www.test.com' ?>

<div ng-app="testApp" ng-init="path='<?php echo $path ?>">
   <div ng-view></div>    
</div>
```

I'm trying to pass the PHP variable to my AngularJS App Config, by this:

```
// Module
var test = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

// Routes
test.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: $rootScope.path + '/pages/display.htm',
        controller:  'testController'
    }) 
});


// Controllers
test.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

This does not work though because the `$rootScope` is not definied. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments about wanting to keep php and scripts separate just add a script tag with a variable that you can then access from anywhere in angular

```
<script>
     var myPathVar = '<?= $someVar; ?>';
</script>
```

Then you can do anything you want with inside angular such as add it as constant , pass it to $rootScope in your config or whatever

Comment: Thank you I've used this approach. Yeah basically if there's no other workaround, I'm doing this. Cool! Cheers for the answer!

Comment: no real need for a workaround. Sure it can be argued it's a global but one global can be tolerated with minimal impact potential

Comment: ***WARNING*** This code is probably vulnerable to cross-site scripting attacks. Do not use this code unless you want your site to be hacked. See [Everything You Need to Know About Preventing Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerabilities in PHP](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know) for an introduction to the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a constant in a script tag in the page generated with PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('testApp').constant('path', '<?php echo $path ?>');
</script>
```

And in your app config:

```
// Routes
test.config(function($routeProvider, path) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: path + '/pages/display.htm',
        controller:  'testController'
    }) 
});
```

If `path` contains any user-supplied content, make sure to escape it appropriately for echoing as a javascript string.

Comment: This may not work if the JS code is wrapped in a `function( $ ) {$(document).ready( ... );} )(jQuery);` type block then you will have to attached it to something global like the window.

Answer (score -1):

you might want do do this instead

```
// Controllers
test.controller('testController', ['<?php echo $scope; ?>', function($scope) {

}]);
```

I dont use angularJs, but regardless  `'$scope'` would literately be the word `$scope`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What can I do if my Angular app is in a separate .js file?

Comment: Pass it to it somehow, hard to answer without knowing how you combine them, also, just as a practice I would avoid using the $ for JS variables, as it is confusing when combined with PHP.

Comment: What would be the point of this? This does not help get OP's php `$path` data into AngularJS's scopes

Comment: @PatrickEvans - well with all $ signed variables, and whatnot ( incomplete example ) I just picked the most obvious issue because in either JS or PHP `'$scope'` is just a word and not a variable.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix unfortunately you can't inject external variables into angular components without registering them ..and $scope is protected in angular also

Comment: I can see how that would be confusing - angular uses the `$` prefix for a bunch of built-in stuff, and uses the variable-names-as-strings thing to make its dependency injection system minification-safe. So that could look like an attempt to use a PHP variable in the javascript